# Shell - export variable name in uppercase

Tags: bash, shell, docker, continuous-integration

I have a ci script called from docker. It's used to define several variables prior to running the tests. Those variable have their name depending on another variable in the ci configuration.

```
export ${VAR_FROM_CI_CONF^^}_FIRST_TEST_VAR="test"
export ${VAR_FROM_CI_CONF^^}_SECOND_TEST_VAR="test2"
```

Locally it works, but running the ci I get `syntax error: bad substitution` error. Looks like it doesn't succeed into interpreting the uppercase in bash style.

I need to replace this so if `VAR_FROM_CI_CONF` is "hi", it would export me :

```
export HI_FIRST_TEST_VAR="test"
export HI_SECOND_TEST_VAR="test2"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned docker, I am guessing that you probably have a container without bash installed (is it Alpine?) and your script is executed with the built in `sh`.

In any case, the `string^^` syntax you are using requires bash 4.0 and above I believe, so you will need to install bash.

If you are on Alpine linux:

```
$ apk add --no-cache bash
$ bash
$ HELLO=hi ; echo ${HELLO^^}
=> HI
```

and then you should be on track.

Of course, if you control your `Dockerfile`, then add the package installation to it with:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
```

and add a shebang to your script, to ensure it is executed with bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing default shell in your container from `/bin/sh` (or whatever) to `/bin/bash`.

This can be done with `SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]` command in Dockerfile. Thus you would get all consequent script commands executed in `bash`, which has good understanding of what is `^^` macro.